# Merge HTML table cells

Tags: html, html-table

I'm creating a table in HTML and I'd I am having a hard time using colspan. Here's a rough drawing: How do I create this?

```
______________________________________________________________
|    Project   |                                              |
|              |                CONTENT 1                     |
===============================================================
|                                  |               |          |
|             CONTENT 2            |   CONTENT 3   |          |
===============================================================
|       |        |        |        |       |        |         |
|   C4  |   C5   |    C6  |  C7    |  C9   |  C10   |   C11   |
_______________________________________________________________
```

This is my code

```
<table align="center" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Project
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" style="width: 95%;">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td>CONTENT 2</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="">
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Show your code, and try to explain better what you have, and what you want to do !

Comment: beautiful drawing! But what's your question?

Comment: I want to know how can i adjust the CONTENT 1 ...because when I try to colspan CONTENT 2 ..content 1 adjust

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution.

- Note #1: consider put a new table inside 3rd TR.
- Note #2: consider using DIVs

```html
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center" scope="col">Project </td>
      <td colspan="5" align="center" scope="col">CONTENT 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" align="center">CONTENT 2</td>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">CONTENT 3</td>
      <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">C4</td>
      <td align="center">C5</td>
      <td align="center">C6</td>
      <td align="center">C7</td>
      <td align="center">C8</td>
      <td align="center">C9</td>
      <td align="center">C10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: sir this works fine..thank you..how can i do this sir..i have edited my question..there is a colspan 2 in the tr..and on the third tr i cannot put colspan because it adjust the upper tr

Answer (score 0):

Your design need two many `colspan` at different places, try to fix column width by adding `<col width="25%">` after `<table>`. below is an example.

```html
<table border=1 width="100%">
<col width="25%">
  <col width="25%">
  <col width="25%">
  <col width="25%">
  <tr>
    <td>Project   </td>
    <td colspan="3" align="center">CONTENT 1  </td>
  <tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">CONTENT 2</td>
    <td align="center">CONTENT 3</td>
    <td></td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<center>
    <table width="50%" border="1" style="line-height:5;text-align:center;">
          <tr>
              <td colspan="2" style="border-left: 3px dashed #35272c;border-right: 3px dashed #35272c;">Project</td>
              <td colspan="6" style="border-right: 3px dashed #35272c;">CONTENT 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="5" style="border-left: 3px dashed #35272c;border-right: 3px dashed #35272c;">CONTENT 2 </td>
              <td colspan="2" style="border-right: 3px dashed #35272c;">CONTENT 3</td>
              <td style="border-right: 3px dashed #35272c;">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td style="border-left: 3px dashed #35272c;">C4</td>
              <td>C5</td>
              <td>C6</td>
              <td>C7</td>
              <td>C8</td>
              <td>C9</td>
              <td>C10</td>
              <td style="border-right: 3px dashed #35272c;">C11</td>
          </tr>
    </table>
</center>
```